# Android Button Icon with Background Color

Tags: android, image, button

[image: I want to create a button like this]

I want to add an image(the user image) in the centre of the button and also maintain the background colour(grey) of the button.

I tried to use the **background** attribute along with the **padding** but it seems to have no effect.

Can anyone please guide me how to do it ?

Should I be using the attributes **drawableTop** etc in my xml ???

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not set the image as the background. Instead, use an ImageButton and specify your image as the source (src attribute).

That way you can specify things such as scale type, padding, etc. Keep in mind that using padding sometimes doesn't work properly on Android version 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for the early reply, but is there no way to achieve this using Button ?

Comment: And if I change my button to an ImageButton, do I have to change the format of my onClickListener() ?

Comment: @swayam nope, Button extends TextView and thus holds text only. ImageButton extends ImageView and thus is capable of holding image content. And no, the listener should work the same, you'll just need to change all references from Button to ImageButton in your java code and xml